# How can I retrieve checkbox array values when the checkbox name is dynamically created?

Tags: php, html

I am dynamically creating forms based on values in a database.  Each form element corresponds to a specific database entry, which includes the name, label, type, and (depending upon the type) possible values to be displayed with the form element.

The name value for each form element is set to the identity column value of the corresponding database entry.

I'm running into a problem when I am working with checkboxes, though.  I'm trying to retrieve the array of selected values, but I am unable to retrieve more than one.  I believe that this is because I am not properly setting the checkbox names to an array, but I am not certain.

Here is where I am generating the checkbox tags:

```
$answers = explode(',',$answerKey);
for($i=0; $i < count($answers); $i++) {
    $questionTag .= "<INPUT TYPE='checkbox' name='$id' value='$answers[$i]' />$answers[$i]";
    }
```

Yet when I post back my results, the results of $_POST["$id"] only returns the last value in the checkbox list.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Instead of `name='$id'` and guess fot the location of the checkbox value, use `name="someOption[]"` with a sensible `value`: all someOptions will now be in an array `$_POST['someOption']`

Comment: Are all the checkboxes relates to one group?

Comment: For any element that has checkboxes, all of the checkboxes will relate to that group, but there can be more than one group of checkboxes on the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$questionTag .= "<INPUT TYPE='checkbox' name='".$id."[]' value='$answers[$i]' />$answers[$i]";
```

Comment: Be aware that will not create a group of checkboxes as this will return only one check box with unique name eg `1[]`

Comment: No, that works perfectly.  It does create a group of checkboxes, since I am iterating through a list of $answers[$i] values, but name='".$id."[]"' gets repeated for each iteration without the $id value changing.